# JavaFX and ProgressIndicator with fxml

Tags: java, javafx

I wonder from morning  how to solve the problem. I have login aplication. When user waiting for login i want use processindicator. I used the second thread but it does not work

Main loader fxml

MainController

```
@FXML public StackPane MainStackPane;

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("/LoginForm/Login.fxml"));
    Pane pane = null;

    try {
        pane = loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());}

    LoginController login = loader.getController();
    login.setMainController(this);

    setScreen(pane, true);
}

public void setScreen(Pane pane, boolean clean){

    MainStackPane.getChildren().addAll(pane);
    }
```

LoginForm:

```
private MainController mainController;
private void Zaloguj() throws IOException {
    String cryptUser = null, cryptPass = null;

    Test test = new Test(this.mainController);
    test.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    LoginSQL sql = new LoginSQL();`
    Byte LoginResult = sql.SQLselect(cryptUser, cryptPass);

    ...}
```

Class Test

```
public class test extends Service<Void>{

private MainController mainController;

public test(MainController mainController) {
    this.mainController = mainController;
}

protected Task<Void> createTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("Service: START");

            ProgressIndicator p = new ProgressIndicator(); 

                     Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                         @Override public void run() {

                    mainController.MainStackPane.getChildren().addAll(p);
                     }});

                if (isCancelled()) {
                    mainController.MainStackPane.getChildren().remove(p);
                }
                return null;
            };};}}
```

ProgressIndicator appears only in the next window after login. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX rendering happens in the main thread only. If you add the `ProgressIndicator` and then use `Thread.sleep()`, JavaFX won't render the indicator until `Thread.sleep()` is done. Also, if the login request hangs, JavaFX will also wait until the login request is complete before rendering.

What you have to do is to make sure to never interrupt/hang the main thread. Remove `Thread.sleep`, and also move your login request to a child thread. When the request is complete, notify the main thread so that it can remove the `ProgressIndicator`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I moved the login to a new thread and i delete the sleep. This is a problem because the thread is started after the entire code has been executed in the method "Zaloguj". Where do I put the code to load the window after the correct login?

Comment: ok its done ! :)
in method Zaloguj:
.runningProperty().addListener(event ->{
FXMLLoader ....